# Convert a website to responsive layout

Tags: responsive-webdesign

We have a website that is not mobile phone optimized. If we want to have a responsive layout, what's the easiest way to go? The design should not be changed, so we don't want to create a website from beginning, but to convert it.

1. Shall we rewrite the HTML/CSS for the whole website?
2. Is **Bootstrap** a good option - if we are not building a new site, but to make it responsive layout on top of our current site?

Comment: second question removed.

Comment: Bootstrap is a library and does not turn a non-responsive site to a responsive one. Bootstrap still requires you to modify the sites HTML. The HTML template or basic design does need to be rewritten though the look and feel can be retained. I suggest hiring a developer with experience if you are unaware of responsive design. There are plenty of gotchas along the way that a good developer will be aware of. This answer may help: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75986/how-to-make-a-website-without-knowing-much-about-css/75988#75988

Comment: @JohnConde This is close enough to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75986/how-to-make-a-website-without-knowing-much-about-css/75988#75988 that it could possibly be marked as a duplicate. I will leave that up to you to decide. They are not exact, but fairly close and could give the OP good guidance. It may be enough to leave the link in the comments too.

Comment: I'll leave the link here so the OP and others can find easily. Since the question is already closed I'll just leave it be so it can ride off into the sunset quietly and peacefully.

Comment: @JohnConde Gotcha! You understand these things far better than I could... so I bow to your expertise. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You start at the beginning. You make a list of things you need to do and want to do (e.g., what sizes do you want to use, 320/640/768/1024?). After that, you plan which you'll do first. I suggest you start with the framework, the global common stuff and work your way into the details.

The annoying thing is you can't (probably) do a small part and upload that (If you can, this would be a very good thing to start with!), because it's weird if your home is responsive, and the followup page isn't.
You can however start preparations. Slowly update your site/HTML/CSS and upload that, but don't activate it. You could make a simple PHP file (with CSS headers) and let that serve the responsive CSS only if accessed by your IP address.

An alternative is making a mobile version, but don't serve everything. In your database you could mark pages as "is_responsive" and only show those pages in your menu (be careful with internal linking!). This way, if your page-template is done and all pages are responsive, you can upload that section (be ware of cache problems!).

**2)** I have very little experience with Bootstrap, but in essence that'll be the same as step 1